# How to close the angular modal after redirecting to another modal?

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

I have a modal like this.

```
const modalRef =this.modalService.open(ABCContentComponent);
 
modalRef.result.then((result) => {
    console.log("Closed");
});
```

Now when I open the modal, then it is going to redirect to a another modal called `DEFContentComponent`. The component contents looks like this.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NgbActiveModal } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-def-content',
  templateUrl: './def-content.component.html',
  styles: [
  ]
})
export class DEFContentComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(public activeModal: NgbActiveModal) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  ngAfterViewInit()
  {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.activeModal.close("Success");
    });
  }
}
```

My question is, how can I close the modal by using `DEFContentComponent`?.

I tried `this.activeModal.close()` and it is not working here. I think that it is because of the redirection. Is there a way to close the modal inside `DEFContentComponent`?

Comment: idk if this helps, but I often close before redirecting. angular material modals end up returning a promise on close and I would usually trigger an opening of another one on that promise. ngBootstrap may be different, but the approach might work

Comment: Actually, redirection happens in the ABCContentComponent, so I can not do the modal closing part first.

Answer (score 0):

you can try .dismiss()

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NgbActiveModal } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-def-content',
  templateUrl: './def-content.component.html',
  styles: [
  ]
})
export class DEFContentComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(public activeModal: NgbActiveModal) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  ngAfterViewInit()
  {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.activeModal.dismiss("Success");
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: sorry. not working...